# Codeigniter 3 grocery crud ajax 403

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have a codeingiter 3 app which uses the grocery crud library.
However,I came across an issue.No ajax-based front-end actions work.The search functionality for example does not work.When i open my browser's dev tools,in the console tab,it displays a 403 forbidden error.However,when i try to visit the page in the browser,it works..

```
$crud = new Grocery_CRUD;
$crud->set_table('clienti');
$crud->set_subject('Client');
$crud->required_fields('nume_client', 'oras', 'adresa');
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using in your controller and/or model to initialize the crud instance?

Comment: sure.  $crud = new Grocery_CRUD;

  $crud->set_table('clienti');
  $crud->set_subject('Client');
  $crud->required_fields('nume_client', 'oras', 'adresa');

Comment: Buna! Surely you are  using more code than that no?  You can edit your original post above and include it there so you can format it nicer.

Comment: Buna :)) well,the controller code is definitely not the issue with this..it works fine except for the ajax requests that grocerycrud automatically makes

Comment: Well I just integrated it in a project myself, and I used this code and it works perfectly.
`function list_customers(){
      if (isset($param)) {
            $this->load->view('list_customers'); 
          }
          $crud = new grocery_CRUD();   
          $crud->set_table('customers_contacts');
          $crud->set_theme('bootstrap'); 
          $crud->columns('acc_id','first_name','last_name', 'city');
          $crud->add_action('View Profile', '', 'customers/view_profile','');
          $output = $crud->render();
          $this->_output($output);
          TEMPLATE::render();
    }`

Comment: Sorry for some reason the last comment got posted incomplete.  In a previous project I had a problem with codeigniter's built in crsf.  Inspect your output code and see if the form has the hidden ci_crsf_token input field.

Comment: In relation to the above, see this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306056/grocerycrud-add-edit-buttons-not-working-when-enabling-codeigniter-csrf-protect

Comment: Thanks,skribe for all your help,but there is no problem with the csrf tokens.I have reviewed that question,but i couldn't find the bug yet..

Comment: however,I am wondering what could cause a 403..

Comment: Alin, have you tried performing any other ajax posts or gets, independent of grocery crud to see if the problem might be somewhere else?